# How to create new instance in MS Sql server management 2012

Tags: sql-server

How to create new instance in server management studio in 2012. can someone help me.
When I am trying to connect to the server its getting failed and showing error 18456.

Comment: Try using correct password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this blog:

[Understanding "login failed" (Error 18456) error messages in SQL Server 2005](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx)

From the blog:

> If the server encounters an error that prevents a login from
>   succeeding, the client will display the following error mesage.
>
> Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Server , Line 1 Login
>   failed for user ''
>
> Note that the message is kept fairly nondescript to prevent
>   information disclosure to unauthenticated clients.   In particular,
>   the 'State' will always be shown to be '1' regardless of the nature of
>   the problem.  To determine the true reason for the failure, the
>   administrator can look in the server's error log where a corresponding
>   entry will be written.  An example of an entry is:
>
> 2006-02-27 00:02:00.34 Logon     Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
>   2006-02-27 00:02:00.34 Logon     Login failed for user ''.
>   [CLIENT: ] n
>
> The key to the message is the 'State' which
>   the server will accurately set to reflect the source of the problem. 
>   In the example above, State 8 indicates that the authentication failed
>   because the user provided an incorrect password.
>
> The common error states and their descriptions are provided in the
>   following table:
>
> ```
> 2 and 5 = Invalid userid
>
> 6 = Attempt to use a Windows login name with SQL Authentication 
>
> 7 = Login disabled and password mismatch 
>
> 8 = Password mismatch 
>
> 9 = Invalid password
>
> 11 and 12 = Valid login but server access failure
>
> 13 = SQL Server service paused
>
> 18 = Change password required
> ```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Take a look this one:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx

You really need to look at the state part of the error message to find the root cause of the issue.

```
2, 5 = Invalid userid
6 = Attempt to use a Windows login name with SQL Authentication
7 = Login disabled and password mismatch
8 = Password mismatch
9 = Invalid password
11, 12 = Valid login but server access failure
13 = SQL Server service paused
18 = Change password required
```